# Removing Carriage Returns in a column

Tags: unix, carriage-return

I have a file in in Unix which has an additional Carriage Return character appearing in a particular field and want to remove it.

I tried printing the ASCII value for the characters in the field and it appears as follows :

> head -1 BVP.csv | cut -d "," -f26 | tr -d "\n" | od -An -t dC
>    34  78  13

Actual values in the field is: "N[Carriage Return]

So I tried removing the carriage return (ASCII value :13) as follows and tried printing the output to a new file, BVP1.csv:

> tr -d '\r' < BVP.csv > BVP1.csv

Then I executed the same command

> head -1 BVP1.csv | cut -d "," -f26 | tr -d "\n" | od -An -t dC

34  78

It prints the ASCII values without the Carriage Return.

But when I open the file in any text editor or even from Windows, I can see that the line breaks into a new record in the file, ie, the additional line feed is not removed.

Can anyone please suggest a method to remove this additional Carriage return appearing in the field.

Thanks in Advance,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet that there's an `LF` (ASCII 10) character after the `CR` (ASCII 13) you're trying to eliminate.  You're not seeing it because of your `tr -d '\n'`.  I'm willing to bet you need to remove both the `CR` and `LF` from field 26 of your BVP.csv.  But, you only want to remove the `LF`s that appear just after a `CR`.

You might try this simple perl recipe to strip all `CR+LF` combos from your csv file, while leaving bare `LF` intact:

```
perl -p -e 's/\r\n//g' < BVP.csv > BVP1.csv
```

This will strip `CR+LF` while leaving `LF` alone.

The reason I think this will do what you want is that bare `CR` without a trailing `LF` are relatively uncommon.  The pre-MacOS X text file formats used `CR` without `LF`.  Since OS X, those have waned in popularity dramatically.