# I want to kill a process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, kubernetes

**I want to delete a process from process list pod_de.csv file**

**Content of pod_de.csv file**

```
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
FebwinterMind-897654db-knbbj    2/2     Running   0          46h
DecNightmarch-897654db-n6qhk    2/2     Running   0          6d10h
DecNightmarch-897654db-v2rgt    0/2     Evicted   0          6d10h
DecNightmarch-897654db-5sswn    0/2     Evicted   0          6d10h
DecNightmarch-897654db-hqntn    2/2     Running   0          6d10h
DecNightmarch-897654db-z42r8    2/2     Running   0          35h
DecNightmarch-765897654db-qgbpb     2/2     Running   0          5d14h
AugNightmarch-774bbfc656-96bs6   2/2     Running   0          6d10h
AugNightmarch-774bbfc656-qnnkt   2/2     Running   0          6d10h
FebwinterMind-765897654db-gk5vw      2/2     Running   0          6d13h
FebwinterMind-765897654db-vhk8p      2/2     Running   0          6d13h
ogfileprocess-5h9ih8934b7b-dpbvt      2/2     Running   0          15h
nedesignprocess-765897654db-rshps     2/2     Running   0          6d10h
nedesignprocess-765897654db-rzqf7     0/2     Evicted   0          6d10h
nedesignprocess-765897654db-sbhps     2/2     Running   0          10h
referencedata-765897654db-xlc82      2/2     Running   0          6d11h
clientmyql-58b7d9b687-f9225   2/2     Running   0          5d18h
clientmyql-58b7d9b687-tfmrl   2/2     Running   0          5d18h
```

I want to kill "**ogfileprocess-5h9ih8934b7b-dpbvt**" process

I implemented this

```
#!/bin/bash
pods=$(kubectl get pods > pod_de.csv)
echo "$pods"
Running_OG_process=$(awk '/ogfileprocess/{print $1}' pod_de.csv)
echo "Running Process:" $Running_OG_process
kubectl delete pod $Running_OG_process
```

**But I am getting additional \r\r\  and due to this it is not killing that particular process**

```
Running Process: ogfileprocess-5h9ih8934b7b-dpbvt
Error from server (NotFound): pods "ogfileprocess-5h9ih8934b7b-dpbvt\r\r" not found
```

**Actual value getting from file is**

```
ogfileprocess-5h9ih8934b7b-dpbvt\r\r
```

**I want**

```
ogfileprocess-5h9ih8934b7b-dpbvt
```

So that I can kill the process.

*Can Someone help me on this, or can we do this in another way. Full code will be highly appreciated*

Comment: the delimiter in your CSV file is `,` Please confirm. Just got confused as spaces are given in the question.

Comment: Actually, After executing "kubectl get pods" I am getting  the running process. Which I wrote into "pod_de.csv" file, And from their I am trying to fetch the required value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing Carriage Returns in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17564838/608639), [Remove carriage returns from CSV data value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46607729/608639), [How do I remove carriage returns from the input file using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33510838/608639), [Remove carriage return in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/800030/608639) and friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do this to delete pod with `ogfileprocess` in its name:

```
kubectl get pods | grep ogfileprocess | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kubectl delete pod
```

Comment: When I am executing directly it is working. But when i am pasting in a file and executing that file then it is not working "error: the server doesn't have a resource type "pod\r"
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "pod\r""

Comment: Looks like you're getting a carriage return (`\r`) in output, try removing it by referring https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix or https://superuser.com/questions/489180/remove-r-from-echoing-out-in-bash-script.